# How to hide angular loading informations in ui-grid in Firefox in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

When I load an ui-grid on my page, angular shows informations in the column headers. I added ng-cloak directive on my ui-grid html tag. But nothing happens.

I added this in my css :

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
display: none !important;
}
```

Not working.

See the result :

[image]

EDIT

This is my ui-grid tag :

```
 <div ng-cloak ui-grid="gridOptions" class="wm-dashboard-grid"
             style="position: relative;top: 0;left: 0;right: 0;bottom: 0;"
             ng-style="resizeWithOffset(400)" resize
             ui-grid-auto-resize
             ui-grid-exporter
             ui-grid-move-columns
             ui-grid-pagination>
            <div class="well grid-loading" ng-if="gridLoading || count==0">
                <i ng-if="gridLoading" class="fa fa-spin fa-spinner"></i>
                <strong ng-if="gridLoading || gridOptions.data.length ==0">Chargement des données...</strong>
                <strong ng-if="!gridLoading && count==0">Pas de données</strong>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Also, I think if you add angular.min.js in the header it should fix your problem. I guess you are adding it in the body

Comment: no, every JS I have are loaded in header tag. I never load a js in the body

Answer (score 0):

Use only **ng-cloak directive to the grid tag header**,

Whenever your data will come then your data will be shown on grid without showing the angularjs expression.